# Copy just ONE database from WAMP to another WAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp

This might be a simple question, but I cant seem to figure it out.
How can I copy just ONE database from one installation of WAMP to another?

All the resources online explain how to transfer ALL data, and migrate.
But I just want ONE database.

Is this possible?

Comment: I should mention, that I dont have the ability to run the other wamp.  Obviously if I did, I would just run it and export the DB.   But all I have is a folder on an external harddrive.

Comment: Not at all sure what you are trying to ask here! So how do you expect to be able to update this other WAMPServers MYSQL instance

Comment: Thats my question.  Can it be done with just access to raw mysql files.  With no ability to export or create SQL files.

Comment: Are the versions of MYSQL the same? Is the database type MYISAM or INNODB